# python curses addstr error - but only on my computer

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I was writing a little program that takes a list and generates a menu out of it in curses (straight up, standard library or whatever, batteries included python's curses) when I noticed the strangest problem (if you'd like, a heavily commented copy of the entire program is below). Simply put, when accepting the results of an `os.listdir` generated list, curses crashes with an `addstr` ERR, BUT, if I feed it a hardcoded list, it works fine. This, of course, makes absolutely no sense, right? A list is a list is a list and a list by any other name should still be a list, right?

To make things even more complicated, I sent the code to a friend of mine who works mainly in python2.6 (mine was originally written to work in python3.1). He uncommented the `broken_input()` call (which feeds the program the `os.listdir` generated information) and said that it worked fine for him. I have both python 2.6 and 3.1 installed, so I changed my shebang to make the program run in 2.6, and (with the `broken_input()` uncommented) for me, it *still* throws the `addstr` ERR (yet runs fine with the hardcoded input... which is, of course, btw, entirely useless apart from proof of concept).

Thus, my question is this: is there something broken in my python installation (I'm running Ubuntu lucid, with python2.6.5 and 3.1 installed), and, if so, how do I fix it so I can get curses to execute this code properly. And, if it's not my python installation, how can I get the same functionality out of curses (i.e.: paint a menu from a list containing an arbitrary number of items, numbering them so that the user can make a selection based on the item number).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.1
"""curses_mp3eater.py: a curses-based implementation of my mp3eater program;
diplays the contents of cwd, allows user to make a selection. But I'm having
problems getting it to iterate over a list.
v0.1 03.14.11
by skookie sprite
address@gmail.com
"""

import curses, curses.wrapper, os, sys


def working_input():
    """the following is demo code to demonstrate my problem... main will accept the following,
    but won't accept the product of a directorylist for reasons that I can't figure out."""
    dircontents=['this','is','a','list','','and','it','will','iterate','fine','in','the','(main) function.']
    return dircontents

def broken_input():
    """this is the code that I NEED to have work... but for reasons beyond me will not iterate in
    the main function. It's a simple list of the contents of the CWD."""
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    dircontents=[]
    for item in os.listdir(cwd):
        dircontents += [item]
    return dircontents

def main(stdscr):
    """This is the program. Designed to take a list of stuff and display it. If I can solve
    that hurdle, I'll add selection mechanisms, and break it across screens - amongst other
    things. But, currently, it can only accept the demo code. Uncomment one or the other to
    see what I mean."""
    #broken_input returns an addstr() ERR, but I don't see the difference between working_input
    #and broken_input as they are both just lists. 
    #working_input() is demo code that illustrates my problem
    stuffin=working_input()
    #stuffin=broken_input()

    #the rest of this stuff works. The problem is with the input. Why?
    linenumber=int()
    linenumber=6
    itemnumber=int()
    itemnumber=1

    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.border(0)

    for item in stuffin:
        stdscr.addstr(linenumber, 10, '%s   -   %s' % (itemnumber, item), curses.A_NORMAL)
        linenumber += 1
        itemnumber += 1

    curses.doupdate()
    stdscr.getch()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: have you tried printing the output of the generated list to see if it in fact looks like a normal list? Perhaps there is a null entry or something in it from the function call that generated it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're stuffing too much onto the screen and thus passing an out-of-bounds line number to `addstr`. If you make an empty directory to run the program in (or enlarge your terminal window), it works.

To fix this, check the number of lines in the window before the output loop in `main`.

Comment: Seems like something `addstr` could/should have reported as part of the error/exception.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the helpful suggestions; I was afraid I'd get ripped apart or something... @larsmans RULES: you were absolutely right on the money; thank you so much. If only I had known about a week and a half ago, I wouldn't have gone nearly half-insane trying to debug every possible aspect of the script. It's so obvious that it's painful, and equally gracious of you to spare the time to help a loser hobbyist like myself. I hope that someday, somewhere, someone slips you twenty bucks.

Answer (score 0):

use `screen.scrollok(1)` after `addstr` to allow the text to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained in the [`addch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Adding-characters) manual page:

> The **`addch`**, **`waddch`**, **`mvaddch`** and **`mvwaddch`** routines put the  character  ch
>   into  the  given  window  at its current window position, which is then
>   advanced.  They are  analogous  to  putchar(3)  in  stdio(3).   If  the
>   advance is at the right margin:
>
> - The cursor automatically wraps to the beginning of the next line.
> - At  the  bottom of the current scrolling region, and if **`scrollok`** is
>     enabled, the scrolling region is scrolled up one line.
> - If **[`scrollok`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_outopts.3x.html#h3-scrollok)** is not enabled, writing a character at the lower  right
>     margin  succeeds.   However, an error is returned because it is not
>     possible to wrap to a new line

The given program neither catches an error from the *lower right margin* (probably should say "corner"), nor calls **`scrollok`** to allow the data to scroll up.  In the latter case, you will lose information which is scrolled up, while handling the exception would allow you to prompt after a screen's worth of data is displayed, and then either quit or display more data.